# Adding Greek letters in existing columns in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

Example table:

```
colA    colB  colC
173743    01  8974
173443    02  8934
173943    05  8924
173243    01  8994
173343    03  8964
```

I want to pass to the third column:

The 3 first numbers from the first column, then add '\delta\sigma', then the rest of the numbers from that column then add the second column.

I tried:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('G82.shp', ['colA','colB','colC']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
       row[2] = row[0].str[:2].add('δσ').add(row[0].str[2:]).add(row[1])
       cursor.updateRow(row)
```

But it doesn't do anything.
It gives:

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you need to update the rows in your loop, otherwise the changes will not be written in the database.

second, your line of code will return some errors. There are different ways to write it but I suggest the use of format().

```
row[2] = "{0}ds{1}{2}".format(str(row[0])[:3], str(row[0])[3:], row[1])
cursor.updateRow(row)
```

EDIT (because of comment mentionning greek letters): not so familiar with greek letter, but you could try unicode characters

"{0}ds{1}{2}" replaced with u"{0}\u0394\u03C3{1}{2}"

Comment: it says: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: ALMOST. UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: ordinal not in range(128) instead of ds is δσ.

Comment: Do you know how to proceed?